# Delete browser related tags

Tags: discussion, status-completed, retagging

There are currently 3 tags relating to the same browser: [ie9](https://windowsphone.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ie9), [browser](https://windowsphone.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/browser) and [internet-explorer](https://windowsphone.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/internet-explorer).

At the moment Internet Explorer 9 is the only browser available (ignoring the apps which just wrap IE up).

I propose retagging all the questions to [internet-explorer](https://windowsphone.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/internet-explorer) or [internet-explorer-9](https://windowsphone.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/internet-explorer-9) (Stackoverflow uses this convention for truly version specific questions) and deleting [ie9](https://windowsphone.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ie9) and [browser](https://windowsphone.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/browser).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the one tagged [browser](https://windowsphone.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/browser) I retagged it to make more sense. [ie9](https://windowsphone.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ie9) has been renamed to [internet-explorer-9](https://windowsphone.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/internet-explorer-9), but I am not sure what to do about [internet-explorer](https://windowsphone.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/internet-explorer)

Think about when an updated IE ships. Do we really want to make everyone choose a specific version? I would imagine most users aren't going to even know.

Does it make more sense to use [internet-explorer](https://windowsphone.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/internet-explorer), and have [internet-explorer-9](https://windowsphone.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/internet-explorer-9) be a synonym?

Comment: A pro-term moderator can always change back from one to the other. So, it doesn't matter whether we choose [tag:internet-explorer] or [tag:internet-explorer-9] for now. What we actually need to see is *how big* an update would be, if it makes the browser quite different the difference in tag might be important. If not, [tag:internet-explorer] would do just fine; although, one still has to wonder in the long end. In about 4 years, would it still be a very similar browser?

Comment: Hopefully MS makes the IE update mandatory. Also considering that most people are on 2-year contracts, I doubt that a significant amount of people will still be using IE9 in 2-4 years.

Comment: I would also think that IE would be tied to the OS version. So if you are running WP 7.5 you are using IE9 and if you are on WP8 you are using IE10. You also made a good point about the user not knowing/caring about the version. So I would think that [tag:internet-explorer] is currently the way to go.

Comment: Any other thoughts/votes? What does it mean if I accept this answer?

Comment: I would take it as IE9 will temporarily be mapped to IE. Once/If we need that changed, we can always switch it back

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know Windows Phone 7 Mango bring IE9 to the fight. But older than this use the IE7 (or IE7 Compact).

In next version probalby we will have another version of browser capable of have css transitions and transforms like IE10 Platform Preview.

Som We need the versioning. I know there aren't so much people with version prior Mango now a days but with the apollo almost here probably we will need questions about IE9 and IE v.next.